# How to change DateTime AM PM format?

Tags: .net, date, datetime, c#-4.0, xamarin.forms

```
        [enter image description here][1]DateTime Mor_Time = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(10, 30, 0);
        Mor_Time  = Mor_Time .Date + ts;        // OutPut :  {5/22/2020 10:30:00 AM}

        DateTime Nigh_Time  = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan ts1 = new TimeSpan(10, 30, -1);
        Nigh_Time  = Nigh_Time.Date + ts1;      //OutPut :  {5/22/2020 10:30:00 AM}
```

I want to following Output format
Mor_Time = 5/22/2020 10:30:00 AM

Nigh_Time =5/22/2020 10:30:00 PM

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Not exactly sure I understand your problem, but how about adding 12 hours (e.g. `Night_Time = Mor_Time.AddHours(12)`)? Also note, that the exact output format (whether it is AM/PM or 24-hours, or else) depends on the format and culture you pass to `DateTime.ToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

OK, there are a couple of things wrong with your code. Let's start with
the output of the values.

Note that the output of a DateTime-Instance is not locale (culture)
specific. That is, the output you see depends on settings of the user that runs
the code. On my system for example, the default output of your `Mor_Time` would
yield: "22.05.2020 10:30:00". That is, 24-hour format. There is a lot to read
about possible date time formats, either [standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings)
or [custom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) formats. Too much to go into in this
answer here. Just make sure you read and understand it, if you want to have a
specific output format, regardless of the regional settings your users may have.
To force the output you show, you would need this:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(Mor_Time.ToString("M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Note that you calculate Mor_Time and Nigh_Time (almost) exactly the same way: using the
current time, ignoring the actual time, adding 10:30 and going with it:

```cs
Mor_Time  = Mor_Time.Date + ts;        // OutPut :  {5/22/2020 10:30:00 AM}
Nigh_Time  = Nigh_Time.Date + ts1;      //OutPut :  {5/22/2020 10:30:00 AM}
```

If one executes your code as it is (plus the date-time format shown above), you get:

```
5/24/2020 10:30:00 AM
5/24/2020 10:29:59 AM
```

Which makes absolute sense, given that:
* You initialize Mor_Time and Nigh_Time with the same day.
* You add 10:30:00 to Mor_Time
* You add 10:29:59 to Nigh_Time (which is what `TimeSpan(10,30, -1)` is)

As I said in my comment to your question, I would have simply written it like this:

```cs
var date = DateTime.Now.Date;
Mor_Time = date + new TimeSpan(10, 30, 0);
Nigh_Time = Mor_Time.AddHours(12);
```

You're code could also work, but then you'd have to add not only 10:30:00 to your
base date value, but 22:30:00 hours. Outputting in 12-hour system with PM/AM
doesn't change the fact that the underlying time is still 22 hours and 30 minutes
in the day. The AM/PM and 12-hour thing is merely an artifact of outputting it
that way (see beginning of this answer), so:

```cs
DateTime Mor_Time = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(10, 30, 0);
Mor_Time  = Mor_Time.Date + ts;
Console.WriteLine(Mor_Time.ToString("M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

DateTime Nigh_Time = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan ts1 = new TimeSpan(22, 30, 0);
Console.WriteLine(ts1);
Nigh_Time  = Nigh_Time.Date + ts1;
Console.WriteLine(Nigh_Time.ToString("M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Things left open:
* Why did you add one second less in your code when attempting to build the 22:30 value?
  (I hope it was not some attempt to compensate the run-time of your code, which would
   be unnecessary and wrong).
* If you really want to build a fixed date/time value like you shown, or you rather need
  a way to convert any AM to PM date/time value.